# Override form data with values

Tags: forms, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a booking page containing a table with a list of bookings. Each row has a button to allow the booking to be edited. When this button is clicked, a modal pop-out form appears using JavaScript with a number of fields. I am passing the `ID` of the booking into the header which works fine.
The `BookingModel` has a list of `BookingViewModels` where the data is stored.

I am trying to set the value of the fields as the values in the Booking model i.e. `@Value = @item.Date` but the data in the box is not overwritten, however if I print the Date on its own underneath it is printed correctly.

How can I print the data within the box?

**Models**

```
public class BookingViewModels
{
    public List<BookingViewModel> BookingModel { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Date
    /// </summary>
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
    public string Date { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Start Time
    /// </summary>
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [Display(Name = "Start Time")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
    public string StartTime { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// End Time
    /// </summary>
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [Display(Name = "End Time")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
    public string EndTime { get; set; }
}

public class BookingViewModel
{
    public int BookingId { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string StartTime { get; set; }
    public string EndTime { get; set; }
    public string inf1 { get; set; }
    public string inf2 { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
//the table with the edit buttons
@foreach (var item in Model.BookingModel)
{
    @{var grid = new WebGrid(Model.BookingModel, canSort: false); }
<input type="button" id="btnaddbooking" class="btn btn-small btn-primary" value="Add Booking" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalbox" />
<hr />
<div class="panel panel-default pre-scrollable">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive table-condensed table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Start Time</th>
                <th>Duration</th>
                <th>End Time</th>
                <th>inf1</th>
                <th>inf2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        @foreach (var item in Model.BookingModel)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @item.Date
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.StartTime
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Duration
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.EndTime
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.inf1
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.inf2
                </td>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Booking", FormMethod.Post))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                    <td>
                        <button class="someButtonClass" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalbox-@item.BookingId" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="someButtonClass2" type="submit" value="Delete" />
                    </td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
}

//the modal form
@foreach (var item in Model.BookingModel)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "Booking", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <div id="modalbox-@item.BookingId" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div id="modal-header" class="modal-header">
                        <h1>Edit Booking #@item.BookingId</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <table id="booking-model-table" class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
                            <tr>
                                <td>Date:</td>
                                <td>
                                    @{
                                        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Date, new { type = "time", @Value = @item.Date })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    }
                                    @item.Date
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Start Time:</td>
                                <td>
                                    @{
                                        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.StartTime, new { type = "time", Value = @item.StartTime })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.StartTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    }
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>End Time:</td>
                                <td>
                                    @{
                                        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.EndTime, new { type = "time", Value = @item.EndTime })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EndTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    }
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">

                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                        <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">Ok</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function () {
var modelbox = function () {
    $("#modalbox").modal("show");
};
$("#btnaddbooking").on('click', modelbox);
});
```

Comment: This page shows a table of bookings, each row within this table has an edit button. Each edit button links to a unique form to allow the information from the selected booking to be loaded into it.

Thanks for the feedback not using the value attribute but could you suggest another way of doing it, that is the question I asked as I do not know how to do it.

The form works for all intents and purposes for booking and validation works correctly. The only thing it does not do correctly is pre-load the values into the form boxes.

Comment: Thanks. I've added more information about the first foreach loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view should be generating one `<form>` element (not one for each `BookingViewModel` in the collection), and then when you click the button, update the values of the form controls with the values of the associated `BookingViewModel`

Start by deleting the `@foreach (var item in Model.BookingModel) {` so only one form is created.

Next replace all `EditorFor()` with `TexBoxFor()` and remove all the `Value = @item.XXX` attributes.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.StartTime, new { type = "time" })
```

In order to add html attributes using the `EditorFor()` method, you must be using MVC-5.1 or higher and the syntax is

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.StartTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "time" } })
```

Your current implementation is not adding any attributes and in any case you should never set the `value` attribute unless you wanting model binding to fail.

Then in your table, add a button for editing the current row

```
<td><button type="button" class="edit" data-id="@item.BookingId">Edit</button></td>
```

and handle the`.click()` event of the button to update the modal's form controls

```
$('.edit'.click(function() {
    $('#BookingId').val($(this).data('id'); // you will need to add a @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.BookingId) to the form
    var cells = $(this).closest('tr').children('td');
    $('#Date').val(cells.eq(0).text());
    $('#StartTime').val(cells.eq(1).text());
    // .... ditto for other values you want to display in the form
    $("#modalbox").modal("show");
});
```

Comment: This looks interesting, Thanks. I'll give it a try as soon as I get chance and get let you know how it goes.